# Are the Google, Youtube, Blogger API Linked Somehow?

Tags: api, youtube, blogger

If I have a user log in to my site with their Google account, using the OAuth2 method, can I use that token to get the users Youtube/Blogger info if they have those accounts linked?

I've read the Youtube and Blogger API's and they both use AuthSub, and are currently compatible with version 2 and older, while Google is version 3.

Do I have to make separate log ins for Blogger and Youtube or is it possible to retrieve that info from the logged in Google account by adding the two scopes to the Google permissions somehow?

Thanks,

Goran

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'll make an educated guess that for privacy reasons you won't be able to get any additional information.

Comment: Can't you try and see what happens?